# Is there any C socket function, which can look for datagrams from a specific UDP client?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, recvfrom

The server I am building uses the UDP transport layer protocol. I have a scenario where multiple clients can send datagrams to my server. But each client may send the data across multiple datagrams, and before starting to process the data, I need to have the entire data at the server. From the man page of `recvfrom()`, it sounds like it reads the datagrams from any UDP client. Are there any `recv*()` family functions that enable us to read from a specific UDP client?

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int append_data(void* buf, int size);

int main()
{
    /* Create a UDP socket and bind to a port */
    int sockfd;
    char rd_buf[100];

    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        /* Recvfrom any client */

        int addr_len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        int rd_status = recvfrom(sockfd, rd_buf, sizeof(rd_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &cliaddr, &addr_len);

        if (append_data(rd_buf, rd_status) == DATA_COMPLETE)
            continue;

        /* Recvfrom a particular client */

        for ( ; ; ) {
            /* Any function similar to recvfromcli() ? */

            int rd_status = recvfromcli(sockfd, rd_buf, sizeof(rd_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &cliaddr, addr_len);

            if (append_data(rd_buf, rd_status) == DATA_COMPLETE)
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

If not what are my other alternatives?

Comment: You can implement a protocol on top of UDP to handle packet sequencing (which could include current packet sequence number and the number of packets to expect, or something similar). You need sequencing anyway, since you could receive the packets in any order. And you should probably implement some kind of timeout and resend functionality as well, because UDP is unreliable and packets can become lost.

Comment: Once you have a protocol to make the communication more reliable (some kind of TCP light), then it's easy to match the packets with their clients, as each packet you receive will have information about the sender. Just keep that information until the full data payload can be reassembled.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is not just the packet sequencing I am worried about, before receiving the entire data from a UDP client, I can receive from the other. It makes my job tough if I need to save the state for every UDP client.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So I cannot achieve this unless I save the state?

Comment: Keep a collection of queues for the incoming packets, one queue per client. When a packet arrives you match the client to its queue, and add the packet. Once you have received all packets for a single client then you can reassemble the payload data and process it. It doesn't matter from which client the current packet comes from, you add it to the correct queue for reassembling, or if it's a new client create a new queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate UDP socket that is `bind()`'ed to the local IP/Port and `connect()`'ed to a specific client IP/Port, then you can `recv()` using that socket, and it will give you datagrams from only that client.

Comment: That seems to be perfectly working. Okay, but let us just say that I am tolerant of other packet losses that happen when I am talking to a specific client, but is there any ``disconnect()`` like functionality afterward? Because my server is not serving that only client and I need to continue the outer for loop. Thanks!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aBFJf54H This is what I am doing as of now, and it is turning its attention towards the first client, while the other client datagrams are just being dropped (any other client is immediately disconnecting).

Comment: @MohithReddy you are not creating a new socket for each "client" detected. You are reusing the same socket, changing its `connect()` association for each datagram received in the outer loop. Also, there is no connection in UDP, so there is no "disconnect". A client would be "disconnected" when it stops exchanging packets with your server. Unless there is a specific "goodbye"-like packet in your protocol, then you need to implement an idle timeout per client.

Comment: @MohithReddy Personally, I wouldn't go this new-socket-connected-per-client approach. I was merely answering your original question as asked. SomeProgrammerDude's suggestion is better and easier to manage for multiple clients